# Datatypes that are represented by a choice of one of many other datatypes

Tags: haskell, types, algebraic-data-types

I am attempting to generate a deck for a toy implementation of Exploding Kittens.

Say I had the following types:

```
data ActionCard = Skip 
  | Attack 
  | Shuffle 
  | Nope 
  | Future 
  | Defuse 
  | Favor
  deriving Enum

data BasicCard = TacoCat 
  | MommaCat 
  | Catermelon 
  | BearCat 
  | PotatoCat 
  | BikiniCat 
  | RainboRalphingCat
  deriving Enum

data Card = ActionCard | BasicCard | BombCard

type Deck = [Card]
```

and a deck generator function like so:

```
generateDeck :: Int -> Deck
generateDeck players = (concat (map (replicate 5) [TacoCat ..])) 
  ++ (replicate 2 Nope)
  ++ (replicate 4 Skip)
  ++ (replicate 4 Attack)
  ++ (replicate 4 Shuffle)
  ++ (replicate 4 Future)
  ++ (replicate 1 Defuse)
  ++ (replicate 4 Favor)
  ++ (replicate (players + 1) BombCard)
```

This fails with:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[BasicCard]’
                    with actual type ‘a7 -> [a7]’
        Probable cause: ‘replicate’ is applied to too few arguments
        In the first argument of ‘(+)’, namely
          ‘replicate (length $ _players state)’
        In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely
          ‘(replicate (length $ _players state) + 1 BombCard)’
```

(and similiar errors for hte other non basic cards)

That makes sense on one level as `(concat (map (replicate 5) [TacoCat ..]))` returns a `[BasicCard]`, however I would have expected the function signature to force a more generic type?

How do allow for `Card` to be either an `ActionCard`, a `BasicCard`, or a `BombCard`?

Comment: Writing `data Card = ActionCard | BasicCard | BombCard` doesn't mean that `Card` will be one of `Attack`, ... , `RainboRalphingCat` - instead it creates three _new_ data constructors that happen to have the same names as three existing types.

Comment: Probably something as `data Card = Action ActionCard | Basic BasicCard | Bomb BombCard` then you'll have to change `[TacoCat ..]` to `map Basic [TacoCat..]` and `Nope`  to `(Action Nope)` and so on...

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> data Card = ActionCard | BasicCard | BombCard
> ```

This creates a new datatype `Card` with three constructors called `ActionCard`, `BasicCard` and `BombCard`. This has nothing to do with the other two datatypes that are called `ActionCard` or `BasicCard`; the namespace of types and constructors is distinct.

What you want to do is to define `Card` as either being an `Action` comprising an `ActionCard`, or a `Basic` `BasicCard`, or a `BombCard`:

```
data Card = Action ActionCard | Basic BasicCard | BombCard
```

then you can make your `Deck` by wrapping each card type in its correct constructor:

```
generateDeck :: Int -> Deck
generateDeck players = basics ++ actions ++ bombs
  where
    cats = concatMap (replicate 5 . Basic) [TacoCat ..]
    actions = map Action . concat $
              [ replicate 2 Nope
              , replicate 4 Skip
              , replicate 4 Attack
              , replicate 4 Shuffle
              , replicate 4 Future
              , replicate 1 Defuse
              , replicate 4 Favor
              ]
    bombs = replicate (players + 1) BombCard
```